# html submit pressed and refresh

Tags: javascript, html, forms, popup

i've got a webpage with a form that has a dropdown selection and a submit button. the page also has a auto refresh function (every 10 secs) to retrieve and display the latest information from the server. when the submit button is clicked, a confirm alert popups with a yes/no option. user then select yes to submit the information to the server. the submission to server works

if the submit is clicked at the same time as the refresh occurred, the confirm dialog box popup but the form information is not submitted. is the confirm box still tied to the form?

here is my code. it may not be exactly the same because im my codes are offline but the geess is

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmSubmit(message)
    {
        var ans = confirm(message);
        if (ans == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    } //end of function
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" method="GET" action="GET">
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="submit" onclick="javascript:confirmSubmit()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use AJAX to refresh the part of the page that needs to be refreshed and thus avoid the race condition?

Comment: you should really not be auto refreshing a page. Use AJAX instead to poll for new information

Comment: yeap i implemented ajax and it works. but im curious how this refresh works. i added a JS timer on the top of the page and a variable which increment every 1 sec and print it on the confirm dialog box. the strange thing is if the submit button is pressed at the same time when the refresh occurred, i could see the incremented value continuing from the current instance on the confirm dialog box. it didnt get reset to zero. this means it didn't reach the new instance of the webpage yet

Comment: i realise that this problem works on any other web page online. for example, i tried creating a database on phpmyadmin. i leave the textbox empty and click go to create a new db while at the same time press f5. i realise the javascript dialog box popup alerting me of entering a db name, but it looks different from the usual alertbox. it seems when that happen, the alertbox behaves differently. does it have to do with child-parent thingy?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to get rid of the auto refreshing so you don't have to worry about the form not being submitted. use AJAX instead to get new information that needs to be updated, this way the page doesn't need to refresh.

If for whatever reason you don't want to remove the auto-refreshing, what I would do is:
where ever you do the auto refreshing, check if the dropdown/form is being shown, and if it is, don't auto refresh.